# Make a method to put different methods in a single for loop respectively?

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, parameters

In a class, I have a lot of algorithmic methods that each one of them needs to be put in a same for loop respectively. Like I need to write a for loop every time when I process an algorithmic methods.
I am trying to make a method as that for loop and can revieve parameters of those algorithmic methods. In that way, I don't need to write the for loop many times, and the program will be smaller, too:)
But when I try to doing it like the common way, it doesn't work since it can wrong the arguments of those algorithmic methods in that method.

---

This is the example of the constant for loop

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 19; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 19; j++){
            if(Main.index[i][j] == "+ "){
               if(Main.winner == "")
                    sampleMethod();
            }   
        }
    }
```

This is the example of my method as that for loop

```
public static void AISteps(AI s){
    for(int i = 0; i < 19; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 19; j++){
            if(Main.index[i][j] == "+ "){
               if(Main.winner == "")
                    s();
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run the program it shows

```
The method s() is undefined for the type AI
```

Is anyone can find any way to get the purpose? THANK YYYYOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

In Java objects are not directly callable. You need to invoke a method on the instance:

```
s.aiMethod();
```

If you want to pass a method as a parameter then you'll need to use a method reference. A method reference allows you to cast a method to an interface with a single method, as long as the return type and parameters are compatible.

In this case you could use the `java.lang.Runnable` interface:

```
public interface Runnable {
    public abstract void run();
}
```

You can refactor your method to accept a method reference easily:

```
public static void AISteps(Runnable method){
    for(int i = 0; i < 19; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 19; j++){
            if(Main.index[i][j] == "+ "){
               if(Main.winner == "")
                    method.run();
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to call it like this for a static method:

```
AISteps(AIClass::someMethod);
```

The same rule applies if the method is an instance method:

```
AIClass myAIClass = ...;
AISteps(myAIClass::someMethod);
```

Comment: Oh! so that's why it threw out errors. However, I am trying to not put a specific method name into that for loop method. I am trying to put something variable in there so I can call any method in there without rewriting the for loops. That is actually the problem>﹏<

Comment: @ZhibinChen I update the answer. Hopefully this solves your issue

Comment: @ZhibinChen note that this is similar to WJS's answer. The lambdas are also cast to single method interfaces, just like the method reference is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered passing `lambdas` to your method and have them called?  Here is a simple example.

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      AISteps(() -> System.out.println("Doit!"));
      AISteps(() -> System.out.println("finished!"));
   }

   public static void AISteps(Runnable fnc) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            /// do some processing here
            fnc.run();
         }
      }
   }
```

Read up on functional references and lambdas to see the various options you can use.

Comment: That sounds cool! Since I am not familiar with the lambda, I am going to look up a little first.